play music automatically by C++ in ubuntu 22.04.5 with ROS2
I'm coding ROS to automatically play musics case by case in Ubuntu 22.04. In detail, purpose of code is noticing the status of robot by speaker. Robot is designed to follow target so if target is neutral play no sound, target is detected play music1, and target is lost play music2

int g_target_detecting_state = 0; // global variable to save status

void clusteringNode::timer_callback()
{
   // Determine status, ROS code 
}

void followingSoundPlay(void) // (const char* filename)
{
    sf::SoundBuffer go_buffer, stop_buffer;

    if (!go_buffer.loadFromFile("audio/music1.wav") || !stop_buffer.loadFromFile("audio/music2.wav"))
    {
        std::cerr << "load failed!";
    }

    sf::Sound go_sound, stop_sound;

    go_sound.setBuffer(go_buffer);
    stop_sound.setBuffer(stop_buffer);

    while(1)
    {
        if(g_target_detecting_state == 0)
        {
            go_sound.stop();
            stop_sound.stop();
        }
        else if(g_target_detecting_state == 1)
        {
            stop_sound.stop();
            go_sound.play();
        }
        else if(g_target_detecting_state == 2)
        {
            go_sound.stop();
            stop_sound.play();
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}

int main(int nArgc,const char* pszArgv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(nArgc, pszArgv);

    auto node = std::make_shared<clusteringNode>();

    std::thread ros_thread([&](){
        rclcpp::spin(node);
    });
    std::thread play_thread(followingSoundPlay);

    if(ros_thread.joinable())
    ros_thread.join();
    if(play_thread.joinable())
    play_thread.join();

    rclcpp::shutdown();

    return 0;
}

This is my code in short. If you need more explain please let me know.
I tried crontab -e to run my code automatically when boot(I heard that systemd is quite fatal so I didn't try so far). Of course I make script and give permission 755 and crontab -e is user crontab.
I run the code manually it works with music, and crontab -e also work but only the music part didn't work. Is there any point I missed? If you find it please let me know
PS. thanks to read my question even thought my bad English.
One thing weird is I tried with 2 PC but one works and other one didn't. Is there any possibility that I installed Ubuntu wrong?

You will need to specify the absolute paths to the audio files instead of relative paths such as "audio/music1.wav".

It might also be that the user does not have the permissions to use the audio.

Thanks to everyone who give advice. Is was cron DISPLAY variable problem. library like SFML should interact with GUI display but cron didn't in default state. So I change my cron to

DISPLAY=:0
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/(number from id -u)
***** /path/of/script


